# Lmod / easybuild categories

Tags: linux, environment-modules, lmod

I'm having my first tinker with modules. I've installed lmod and easybuild and have built a package (SAMtools) with its dependencies.

Running `module av` shows the modules are available. It lists them twice, once in the 'all' category and also in their relevant category. If I try to load a module like `bio/SAMtools`, it complains that it can't find the dependencies. I assume this is because it's looking for `ncurses` when it needs to look for `all/ncurses` or `devel/ncurses`.

I know I could just change the modulepath to point straight at the `all` directory instead of the directory containing the category directories but wanted to know if this was the correct approach or if I'm doing something wrong and `module` should be able to locate the module dependencies..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module` (whether it is Environment Modules or Lmod) looks for the module name as a directory under the enabled modulepath. So if your enabled modulepath is `/path/to/modulefiles`, if you try to load `devel/ncurses` it will look at version files under `/path/to/modulefiles/devel/ncurses` directory.

As the modules generated by easybuild defines dependency as `ncurses` and not `all/ncurses` or `devel/ncurses`, it means the modulepath to enable should be `/path/to/modulefiles/all` or `/path/to/modulefiles/devel`.

[Locating modulefile](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulefile.html#locating-modulefiles) section in modulefile(4) man page gives details on how modules are searched. This is the documentation for Environment Modules, but the mechanism is quite similar on Lmod.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of what I was thinking - just wanted to confirm I hadn't got it wrong. Just seems a bit of a waste for easybuild to nicely categorise the packages, just to point lmod at 'all' and ignore the categories..

Comment: The reason that EasyBuild has the categorized modules as well is so you can pick: either you add the `<prefix>/modules/all` directory to `$MODULEPATH`, or you add all the different `<prefix>/modules/<category>` paths to `$MODULEPATH` (except for `.../all`).
With the latter, you'll have more structure in the output of "`module avail`" compared to just having one "bag" of modules when using `<prefix>/modules/all`